# Unknown Android Device - linux mint

Tags: android, linux, adb, linux-mint

I have linux mint 11.
When i do ./adb devices i see ???? non permision.(eclipse the same).
I create 50-android.rules and insert

```
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0FCE", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

then `restart udev(shortcut); ./adb kill-server ; ./adb start-server`, but still not work.

Is this configuration correct for my system linux mint 11 and my phone sony ericsson xperia x10 ??

EDIT: Sorry i have LINUX MINT 12 (gnome 3?). I had wrong sys info in one file. Is it change anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux Mint 11 I had to create the file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules and I added:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04E8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

I used both upper and lower case because I was having lots of problems with 1 single entry in the rules file. The id 04E8 is for Samsung, use the right id for Sony Ericsson.

I restarted my laptop to make sure that all worked. This is overkill and restarting udev should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I am still a newbie to linux AND android development but I finally got my device recognized.  The key (I THINK) was to change SUBSYSTEM to SUBSYSTEMS and ATTR to ATTRS.  According to the [udev(7) page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udev), this "searches the devpath upwards for a matching device..."  So, this is what I ended up doing for an HTC Incredible 2:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Then I added this single line to the file

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Then I restarted udev and adb (not sure if all of these are necessary).  I also may have unplugged / plugged in my usb android connection (can't remember):

```
sudo restart udev
adb kill-server
adb restart-server
adb devices
```

After this, the ???????? went away from the adb devices results and instead I got something like
    HT14PMA...     device

Like I said above, I'm a newbie and I'm not sure how much of what I did was necessary.  I think the key may have been adding the "S" to SUBSYSTEMS to search multiple paths.  It's also possible I was doing other things wrong.  Here's the most helpful pages I found

For hint on how to restart udev: http://dimitar.me/how-to-connect-your-android-phone-to-ubuntu-to-do-developmenttestinginstallations-or-tethering/

Android developers guide (got me close): http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

udev(7) Linux man page: http://linux.die.net/man/7/udev

EDIT: After getting the device recognized, I started eclipse (indigo) and successfully ran a "hello world" app on the connected phone.  However subsequent to that I started getting problems connecting w/ eclipse (telling me it couldn't find adb connection).  So maybe my above advice is not sufficient and / or I have other problems.  The adb connection problem in eclipse is intermittent, so clearly something is still not quite right.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me...pasted the line above into my 51-android.rules file (after trying a lot of other examples on the web), and after restarting udev and adb I was able to get Linux Mint to recognize my legacy test device.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 51-android.rules

/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Comment: I tried aslo 51/70/71/99 and still no permission :( Maybe content of file depend of version of mint ? I can' t find info about it